# (My)SQL optimization question

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I have an SQL, which takes more than minute to execute, which is too much for me, can someone give advice on optimization.

UPDATE 2 - a little modified sql with increase of speed:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
kw.`id` ,  kw.`clientid` ,  kw.`day` ,  kw.`campaignid` ,  kw.`campaign` ,  kw.`adgroupid`,  kw.`adgroup` ,  kw.`matchtype` ,  
kw.`firstpagecpc` ,  kw.`keywordtext` ,  kw.`qualityscore` ,  kw.`maxcpc` ,  kw.`avgcpm` ,  kw.`status` ,  kw.`keywordtext` ,  
kw.`matchtype` ,

SUM( kw.`impressions` )                                                  AS impressions,
SUM(  kw.`clicks` )                                                      AS clicks,
SUM(  kw.`impressions` *  kw.`avgposition` ) / SUM(  kw.`impressions` )  AS avgposition, 
SUM(  kw.`cost` )                                                        AS cost,
(SUM(  kw.`clicks` ) / SUM(  kw.`impressions` ) *100)                    AS ctr,
(SUM(  kw.`cost` ) / SUM(  kw.`clicks` ))                                AS avgcpc,
IF(kw.maxcpc = 0,kw.maxcpc,ad.defaultmaxcpc)                             AS maxcpc

FROM  `keywordsreport`                                                   AS kw
JOIN  `adgroupreport`                                                    AS ad 
ON (kw.clientid = ad.clientid AND kw.`day` = ad.day)

WHERE  
kw.`campaignid` = '55347673'
AND kw.`clientid` = '6588826821'
AND kw.`day` BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-07-31'
AND (kw.`adid` = '' OR kw.`adid` = '0')
GROUP BY kw.`keywordtext`, kw.`matchtype`
```

keywordsreport table indexes:

```
PRIMARY  PRIMARY 235232  id

Unique   UNIQUE  235232  adgroupid
                         day
                         keywordtext
                         matchtype
                         adid
INDEX    INDEX   16802   keywordtext
                          matchtype
                          clientid

CLIENTIDDAY  INDEX   6637 clientid
                          day
```

adgroupreport table indexes:

```
PRIMARY          PRIMARY 1328238  id

CLIENTIDDAY  INDEX   6447     clientid
                                  day
```

UPDATE 3:
Sample query with EXPLAIN:

```
    i  select_type  table   type    possible_keys                                      key                key_len   ref     rows    Extra
    1   SIMPLE      kw      range   CLIENTID,CLIENTIDDAY,ADIDDAY,CAMPAIGNCLIENTDAY     CAMPAIGNCLIENTDAY  211   NULL    350 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
    1   SIMPLE      ad      range   CLIENTIDDAY                                        CLIENTIDDAY        65    NULL    42464   Using where
```

In each table: keywordsreport AND adgroupreport there could be ~ 1 000 000 records.

Comment: how many rows in each table?  how many rows with adid of 0 or null?  how many rows per campaignid?

Comment: Try putting `EXPLAIN` in front of the query and then post the results here

Comment: Does this query run 50% faster without the join on `adgroupreport` and selecting `maxcpc`?

Comment: Without join it runs 10-15 times faster, speed is acceptable. But what to use instead of join?

Comment: As I mentioned in Update 1, there could be ~ 1 000 000 rows in each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go one step further...  A client can have many campaigns, so your index should be on the smallest criteria first.  I  would have an index on

```
( CampaignID, ClientId, Day )
```

then just for grins to match the anticipated index for optimizing, just adjust the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE
         kw.campaignid = '23213231232'
      AND kw.clientid = '$clientid'
      AND kw.`day` BETWEEN '2011-07-31' AND '2011-07-01'
      AND ( kw.adid = '' OR kw.adid = '0')
```

Comment: Tried, no significant increase. Even slight decrease of speed on some queries (-1 sec). But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Vitaliy: You can also try with `(CampaignID, Adid, ClientId, Day )` index

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need indexes on clientid and or campaignid.  tough without more details.

Comment: Provided with more details ( EXPLAIN SQL, INDEXES, number of rows - 1 000 000 ). Thanks!

Comment: well.. the index on client id and campaign id are exactly the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

The unique index in kw table can't be used because you have no adgroupid in your where clause.
create an index on clientid, day

Comment: Unique index is used on insert, it is made to have a check of duplicate data also on DB layer. Created index, it gave a little performance increase. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple Query for Optimization,

Employee table
It has two column,like
id Totalmarks(out of 900)
1  700
2  600
.  .
.  .
n  .

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Totalmarks BETWEEN 300 AND 600
```

it will take time for execution query few second.

but

```
ALTER TABLE Totalmarks ADD INDEX ( Totalmarks  );
SELECT * FROM Employee  WHERE Totalmarks BETWEEN 300 AND 600;
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are the two indexes recommended by online PawSQL tool,

```
CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX1564931998 ON keywordsreport(campaignid,clientid,keywordtext,matchtype);
CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX1028958902 ON keywordsreport(campaignid,clientid,day);
```

Looks the first help your to quickly filter the data and avoid sorting; the second one just help your to filter your data quickly.  Try them and pick the fast one.